# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were detected

Tags: .net, xamarin, frontend, maui, comexception

Context: We have recently ported an old Xamarin.Forms project into .NET MAUI. We now have the app opening and a working login. The Main Page after logging in is a page where users can log their actions. Currently, if I have a log from the previous day and click an arrow on the page to go see it, I recieved the No Installed Components Detected issue on my SETMODELBINDING method, which is the last method listed below.
The following is redacted code:

```
public DailyLogPage(int dailylogid = 0)
{
    dlog = new DailyLogControl();
    myid = Guid.NewGuid();
    loadingControl = new LoadingControl();
    this.Title = "Daily Log";
    IconImageSource = "Navigation_Add.png";
    this.Disappearing += MainViewPage_Disappearing;
    BasePage.InitPage(this);

    SetDataRepository();
    InitializeCriteria();
    CreateDailyLogUI();
    CreatePageActions();
    SetMessagingCenterSubscriptions();
    SetHomeOpco();
    AutoSaveAndSync();
}

#region UICode
private void CreateDailyLogUI()
{
    CreateTxtDevice();
    CreateGrid();
    CreateMainScrollView();

    stackBody.SetBinding(StackLayout.BackgroundColorProperty, "PageColor.BodyBackground");
    this.SetBinding(ContentPage.BackgroundColorProperty, "PageColor.PageBackground");
    SetModelBinding(dailylogCriteria.DailyLog);
}

private void CreateTxtDevice()
{
    txtDevice = new AutoCompleteView
    {
        Placeholder = "Enter text",
        ShowSearchButton = false,
        SuggestionsHeightRequest = 120,
        SelectedCommand = new Command(() => { }),
    };
    txtDevice.EntText.IsVisible = false;
}

private void CreateGrid()
{
    AddButton = new Button
    {
        HeightRequest = 45,
        ImageSource = "add_data.png",
        BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent
    };
    AddButton.Clicked += AddButton_Clicked;

    sideStack = new StackLayout();
    grid = new Grid
    {
        ColumnDefinitions =
            {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(.05, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(.5, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(9.45, GridUnitType.Star) },
            }
    };

    grid.Children.Add(sideStack);
    Grid.SetColumn(sideStack, 0);

    sideStack.Children.Add(AddButton);
    grid.Children.Add(sideStack);
    Grid.SetColumn(sideStack, 1);
}

private void CreateMainScrollView()
{
    dailyLogHeader = new DailyLogStepControlHeader() { IsClippedToBounds = true };
    stack = new StackLayout { };
    var scrollView = new StackLayout { Children = { stack } };
    dailyLogSyncControl = new DailyLogSyncControl { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, IsClippedToBounds = true };

    //Create StackBody
    stackBody = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 30),
        Children =
        {
            dailyLogHeader,
            scrollView
        }
    };

    //Create StackMain
    stackmain = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(7),
        Children =
        {
            dlog,
            stackBody,
            dailyLogSyncControl
        }
    };

    //Create MainScrollView
    mainScrollView = new ScrollView { Content = stackmain };
    Content = mainScrollView;
}
private void CreatePageActions()
{
    #region actions
    //wire up the next & previous page action button commands here
    Action NextPage = async () =>
    {
        if (!model.DailyLog.ValidData)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(UIConstants.TITLE, "Location & Purpose are required.", "Ok");
            return;
        }

        await model.SaveData(true);

        if (dailylogCriteria.HasNext)
        {
            dailylogCriteria = _data.GetNextDailyLog(model.DailyLog.DailyLogId);
        }
        else
        {
            var newDlog = CreateDailyLog(false);
            await _data.SaveDailyLog(newDlog);
            dailylogCriteria = _data.GetLastDailyLog();
        }
        SetModelBinding(dailylogCriteria.DailyLog);

    };

    Action PreviousPage = async () =>
     {
         await model.SaveData(true);

         if (dailylogCriteria.HasPrevious)
         {
             dailylogCriteria = _data.GetPreviousDailyLog(model.DailyLog.DailyLogId);
         }
         else
         {
             return;
         }

         SetModelBinding(dailylogCriteria.DailyLog);
     };

    Action<int> GotoPage = (pageid) =>
    {
        //CAN THIS FUNCTION EVER BE RUN?
        //await model.SaveData(true);
        //if (pageid > 0 && pageid <= dailylogCriteria.TotalDailyLogs)
        //{
        //    SetModelBinding(model.DailyLog);
        //}

    };
    #endregion

    dlog.SetNextPage(NextPage);
    dlog.SetPreviousPage(PreviousPage);
    dlog.SetGotoPage(GotoPage);
    dlog.IsClippedToBounds = true;
}
private DailyLog CreateDailyLog(bool isLogin)
{
    var newDlog = new DailyLog();
    //This is redacted data. just setting DailyLog properties to user data(ie, username, opco, etc)

    return newDlog;
}

private void SetModelBinding(DailyLog dailyLog)
{
    stackmain.Children.Remove(dlog);

    model = new DailyLogViewModel(dailyLog)
    {
        IsFetching = true,
        PageCount = dailylogCriteria.TotalDailyLogs,
        PageNo = dailylogCriteria.CurrentPage
    };

    BindingContext = model;
    
    stackmain.Children.Insert(0, dlog);   <---- THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    stack.Children.Clear();
    ToggleLoading();
    //remove old controls
    Task.Delay(300).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await FetchData();
            }
            catch
            { //try one more attempt from sql lite
                await ReFetchData();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can also check this doc by official: [Dispatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.dispatching.dispatcher?view=net-maui-8.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were >detected
>
> ```cs
> stackmain.Children.Insert(0, dlog);   <---- THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
> ```

About this, I find an issue on MAUI GitHub: [[Windows] Faced no installed components were detected exception
#8997](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8997), you can try the [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8997#issuecomment-1495049395) mattleibow provided:

> I think it may be because you are adding a child during a layout cycle? >Maybe you can avoid this by adding via a dispatch. This should cause the >child to be added after the layout is complete:
>
> ```cs
> this.Owner.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => this.Owner.Children.Add(myLabel));
> ```

Hope it can help you.